# Convert string of byte array to byte array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a byte array like so

```
 data = bytes([0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00])

 string_data = str(data)

 print(string_data)
 # "b'\\x13\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x08\\x00'"
```

I want back byte array from string of data

```
data = string_of_byte_array_to_byte_array(string_data)

print(data)
# b'\x13\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00'
```

Comment: Note that `str(some_bytes)` is almost never the right thing to do in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to revert the string to bytes. (Thank you at Matiiss and Mark Tolonen for pointing out the [problems with the `eval` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698/15873043))

```py
from ast import literal_eval

data = literal_eval(data_string)
```

Comment: you should add tho that using `eval` is not safe

Answer (score 2):

`ast.literal_eval` will undo `str` on a `bytes` object:

```py
>>> data = bytes([0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00])
>>> s = str(data)
>>> s
"b'\\x13\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x08\\x00'"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
b'\x13\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00'
```

But there are better ways to view byte data as a hexadecimal string:

```py
>>> data.hex()
'130000000800'
>>> s = data.hex(sep=' ')
>>> s
'13 00 00 00 08 00'
>>> bytes.fromhex(s)
b'\x13\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a_string = ‘abc’
encoded_string = a_string. encode()
byte_array = bytearray(encoded_string)
```